# present viewController inside custom view in swift

Tags: ios, view, viewcontroller

I have custom view (sort of menu), which contains a button. I want to open a new view controller by clicking this button. How can i write this method in my view class? the problem is that i can't present VC inside a view.

Answer (score 0):

You need a ViewController. You could [write your own Protocol Methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html) and handle it over those, or you could use [NSNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to communicate between View and Controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own protocol or NSNotification if you want to present controller from current UIViewControlller.

OR

If you just want to present controller from your custom view you can use this code.

```
let appdelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let viewcon = appdelegate.window?.rootViewController
        let controller = YourViewController()
        viewcon?.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```